# panic: runtime error: index out of range [20] with length 14

Tags: golang

```
package main

import "errors"

func GetCharacterAtPosition(str string, position int) (rune, error) {
    if position < 0 || position >= len(str) {
        return 0, errors.New("position out of range")
    }
    return []rune(str)[position], nil
}
```

Выдает ошибку:panic: runtime error: index out of range [20] with length 14
Как исправить?

Comment: В выражении `len(str)` вы считаете количество байт в строке, а в `[]rune(str)[position]` пытаетесь получить юникодный символ — символов в строке может быть меньше чем байтов

Comment: так как это исправить можно?

Comment: Я не очень знаю golang, но разве если нумерация строки с 0, то выражение должно быть вроде так: if position < 0 || position < len(str), так проще - ?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно проверять длину массива рун

```go
func GetCharacterAtPosition(str string, position int) (rune, error) {
    runes := []rune(str)
    if position < 0 || position >= len(runes) {
        return 0, errors.New("position out of range")
    }
    return runes[position], nil
}
```